# Proguard fails if jar is empty

Tags: proguard

I'm using proguard to obfuscate my code. My setup is I have 1 parent `pom.xml` and about 50 modules underneath. The problem is some of these jars are *empty* (I will implement those later), others contain only property files (kind of like `spring-boot-starter` jars) and some others are `webjars` (they only have css, js, and images) and the proguard maven plugin fails because proguard complains the source is empty:

```
[proguard] Error: The input doesn't contain any classes. Did you specify the proper '-injars' options?
```

Is there a setting in proguard to silently ignore those jars and not break the whole build? To me it sounds like this must be printed as a warning instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened a pull-request for proguard here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/code/merge-requests/1/

Now we wait for it to be merged :)

Comment: This also happens if you use an empty directory and it is not fixed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you input an empty directory, I just added a dummy class to the root package.